# Create RTMP streams for the client requests using RED5 server application

Tags: java, red5, rtmp, rtmps

I am working on code snippet where I want to create an RED5 rtmp stream using RED5 server application. I have been searching since 5 days to get a good tutorial about the same.

All the tutorials or questions on the stackoverflow discuss about either RTMP client side code or isssues with streaming using oflademo.

What I have achieved ?

1. I have successfully installed and ran RED5 on my ubuntu box.
2. I have installed RED5 Eclipse IDE plugin and created one sample project with RED5 runtime code generation
3. I could see oflademo app streaming videos on rtmp

What I want to achieve ?

1. Have a server side jsp page showing number of connections i have received.

   - For this i did one small test like I defined welcome-file in web.xml withing the project i generated using plugin. But i couldnt reach to that file but at the same time if I create a project using simple eclipse wizard for tomcat my welcome file thing works.
2. After getting each request I want to start an rtmp stream for that client.

   - I tried reading code of oflademo but really couldnt understand the code. Most of the things are commented or probably something I am missing while reading that code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to start an RTMP stream for that client"? An RTMP connection already creates an RTMP "stream"; do you want a Shared Object or a Video?

Comment: I want to stream a video based on parameter that my client is sending to server.

Comment: One thing I found that, Red5.0 RC 1 is kind of buggy..i Just shifted to 0.9 and my connection started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found is to go back to 0.9 version, 1.0 RC has some issues. I switched back to 0.9 and everything seems working.

Comment: Thanks to @seba.wagner I am able to deploy my app on Red5 1.0 RC2. Basically Red5 plugin for eclipse generates an outdated code which has old paths in the configuration. one change you have to make is <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register"> in red5-web.xml